# Showing a structure is minimal

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Underlying set of structure is $\mathbb{N}$ , our language only have (<) interpreted as usual order.  Why is this minimal? (Every definable subset finite or cofinite)

I try to show with contradiction that we have set not of this form (so definable set which is infinite but not cofinite) but I cannot see how to describe this with only this order relation <. I first try to see without quantifiers, which is not hard, but when quantifiers come I begin to have troubles. Please give advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, remark that $\omega \equiv \omega +\zeta$ where $\zeta$ is the order type of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. The language is always $<$, I omit it in notion. Next since the automorphism group of $\omega+\zeta$ is transitive on $\zeta$ any definable subset of $\omega+\zeta$ must either contain or be disjoint from $\zeta$.

Now assume that $\varphi(x)$ defines an infinite, coinfinite subset of $\omega$ then 
$$\omega \vDash \forall x\exists y (x<y\wedge \varphi(y))$$
$$\omega \vDash \forall x\exists y (x<y\wedge \neg\varphi(y))$$ and thus $\omega+\zeta$ must satisfy the same formulas. This contradicts the earlier remark about the subset of $\omega+\zeta$ defined by $\varphi$.

Comment: Just a few things? How do you know that automorphism group will be transitive, and also please explain the formulas you defined for the ordinal ω? Thanks.

Comment: $n\mapsto n+k$ is an automorphism of the $\zeta$ part. I dont understand the second question.

Comment: I understand use of $\phi $  but not of the conditions in the quantifier scope. Why is it necessary to  intersect with the condition that $x<y$? They are stating that , given $x$, we have bigger $y$ that satisfies $\phi$, and then that we have a bigger $y$ that does not satisfy $\phi$. But if $\omega + \zeta $ satisfying these formulas, then we can not have both infinite and coinfinite, but I do not see how to reach conclusion?

Comment: I probably should not have done that so soon, and asked you first. I thought I understand the process of what you did, but now I analyse it myself and try to do it in detail, and see I don't know completely. Sorry.

Comment: The formulas say that $\varphi$ and $\neg \varphi$ are cofinal. This cannot happen in $\omega+\zeta$ since the auto group is transitive on $\zeta$, thus it cannot happen on $\omega$ since the structures are elementarily equivalent.